# Catch all routing with params

Tags: express

I want to make a simple application and one of the requirements is to capture everything after the URL. But these params will contain slashes/dots and what not. Like:

`localhost:3030/file1.html+css/test.css`

I basically want to put everything after `localhost:3000/` into the params and then deal with that individually. How do I do so? I've used `app.get('/:string')` but that doesn't work if there is a slash in the URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `req.url`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(app.router);
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
  console.log('req.url');
  console.log(req.url);
  // from here you might want to use url.parse:
  // http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost
  res.send(200)
});

//Output:
$ curl http://localhost:3000/foo?bar=baz#hash
  req.url
  /foo?bar=baz
```

Comment: Be aware that if you or some other middleware modifies `req.url` express stores the original as `req.originalUrl` [(docs)](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.originalUrl)